# PyCharm - How to setup a mysql database connection

Tags: pycharm

I've just started programming Django in the PyCharm editor. I would like to setup a connection to a mysql-server on the Internet. So I clicked on `Data Sources` > `DB Data Source`.

Here's where the horror starts. I've to pick a `JDBC Driver File`, I don't know which one I need to choose, I suppose `MySQL Connector`. After that I need to pick a `JDBC Driver Class`, just guessing but I would take the `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`. In addition I've to specify a `Database URL` beginning with `jdbc://`. I've never heard of *JDBC* and all that stuff.

Would be great if you could help me out here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to *Data Sources and Drivers* and press **+** button.

From *Drivers* list select MySQL.

If you are doing this for the first time a '*Download missing drivers files*' will appear at the bottom of the window. If you click it, it will download the latest driver for this connection.
You can also click on the *Driver: MySQL* link > *Go to Driver* and go to drivers config page. *JDBC Driver Class* should be set to `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` by default. You can install older versions of drivers by clicking **+** button.

On Project Data Sources page fill in *Host* (IP or hostname), *port* (3306 by default), *User* and *Password*. Filling *Databese* is optional.

URL for connection should be `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306` or `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname` if you specified database name.

Documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/data-sources-and-drivers-dialog.html

Here is *Data Sources and Drivers* window from *PyCharm 2019.2*.

[image: Data Sources and Drivers]